# How to find the average Kendall's distance between 2 rankings

Tags: permutations, problem-solving

Suppose I have 2 rankings:

$1$, $2$, $3$ and $2, 1, 3$ then the Kendall's distance between the two is 1 since there is only one pairwise adjacent switch.

My question is, suppose my 2 rankings each consist of 3 items, then what's the average Kendall's distance between them? What's the average distance between 2 rankings with 8 items? Or X items?

I tried permuting all possible cases of rankings with 3 items (i.e. {1, 2, 3}, {1, 3, 2}, {3, 1, 2}, {3, 2, 1}, {2, 3, 1}, {2, 1, 3} and then calculating the Kendall's distance from each ranking to all the other ones. Then I took the average and got 1.5. Not sure if that's correct, and rankings with lots of items become computationally difficult for me, so I was wondering if there's a more straightforward solution.

note: couldn't find a suitable tag so I just used permutation

Comment: There's a very simple argument that the average distance is $n(n-1)/4$ using linearity of expectation: any given pair of indices contributes $0$ or $1$ to the distance exactly half of the time, so the $n(n-1)/2$ pairs contribute an average of $n(n-1)/4$.  Linearity of expectation means that even if the contributions are not independent, that has no effect on the average value of the total (though it certainly could affect the shape of the distribution).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my comment in answer form, which I believe should be a simpler presentation than igb's answer (which seems correct to me, though I haven't checked the fine details).

Let $\sigma,\tau$ be two independent randomly chosen permutations.  Then the Kendall distance between $\sigma$ and $\tau$ is equal to the number of inversions in $\sigma^{-1} \tau$.  Since multiplication by any fixed $\sigma^{-1}$ is a bijection on the finite space of permutations, the distribution of $\sigma^{-1} \tau$ is also uniformly random.  So we may equivalently consider the expected number of inversions in $\tau$ itself.

For any $1\le i<j\le n$, let $X_{ij}(\tau)$ be the indicator variable which takes the value $1$ if $\tau(i) > \tau(j)$ and $0$ otherwise.  Then by symmetry the expected value of $X_{ij}(\tau)$ is $1/2$ (for instance, pre-multiplication by the transposition $(i,j)$ maps bijectively between the permutations where $X_{ij} =0$ and the permutations where $X_{ij}=1$).  Furthermore, the precise number of inversions in $\tau$ is exactly $\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \sum_{j=i+1}^n X_{ij}(\tau)$.  By linearity of expectation, the expected value of this sum is equal to the sum of each expectation, or $1/2$ times the number of terms $X_{ij}$.  This gives $n(n-1)/4$.

Answer (score 3):

Erick Wong has already given the correct answer to your question, which is $\frac{n(n-1)}{4}$. Here is my attempt at a proof by induction.

Due to symmetry, we do not need to consider the entire matrix of distances between permutations, which is of size $n! \times n!$. It is enough to look at the distances between the naturally ordered ranking $(1, 2, ..., n)$ and all $n!$ permutations (including itself). In this case, each distance is equivalent to the number of inversions, i.e. pairs $i < j$ such that $\sigma(i) > \sigma(j)$. We then go on to prove the following (equivalent) statement:

$P(n)$: The average number of inversions of $\{1, 2, ..., n\}$ across its permutations is $ \frac{n(n-1)}{4}$.

We now show that $P(n)$ holds for any $n \ge 1$.

**Basis:** The statement obviously holds for $n = 1$. $\{1\}$ has only one permutation, namely $(1)$, which has $0 = \frac{0 \cdot (-1)}{4}$ inversions.

**Inductive step:** We show that if $P(k)$ holds, then $P(k+1)$ holds.

We split our $(k+1)!$ permutations into $k+1$ sets of $k!$ permutations according to the position of the newest item in the set, $k+1$.

*Case 1:* We consider permutations of the form $(\sigma(1), \sigma(2), ..., \sigma(k), k + 1)$, where item $k+1$ is in the $k+1$-th position. From $P(k)$ we have that the average number of inversions of the items $\{1, 2, ..., k\}$ is $\frac{k(k-1)}{4}$. Since $k+1$ is the largest item, the new item pairs $(\sigma(i), k+1)$, $i \in \{1, 2, ..., k\}$, do not constitute any additional inversions.

*Case 2:* We consider permutations of the form $(\sigma(1), \sigma(2), ..., \sigma(k-1), k + 1, \sigma(k))$, where item $k+1$ is in the $k$-th position. From $P(k)$ we have that the average number of inversions of the items $\{1, 2, ..., k\}$ is $\frac{k(k-1)}{4}$. Since $k+1$ is the largest item, the new item pairs $(\sigma(i), k+1)$, $i \in \{1, 2, ..., k-1\}$, do not constitute any additional inversions. The pair $(k+1, \sigma(k))$, on the other hand, is always an inversion. This increases the average number of inversions for the set of $k+1$ items to $\frac{k(k-1)}{4} + 1$

We follow this line of reasoning until we reach the final case...

*Case k+1:* We consider permutations of the form $(k + 1, \sigma(1), \sigma(2), ..., \sigma(k-1), \sigma(k))$, where item $k+1$ is in the first position. From $P(k)$ we have that the average number of inversions of the items $\{1, 2, ..., k\}$ is $\frac{k(k-1)}{4}$. Since $k+1$ is the largest item, the new item pairs $(k+1, \sigma(i))$, $i \in \{1, 2, ..., k\}$, all constitute additional inversions. This increases the average number of inversions for the set of $k+1$ items to $\frac{k(k-1)}{4} + k$.

We now combine the average number of inversions of the $k+1$ disjoint sets of $k!$ permutations to obtain the average number of inversions of $\{1, 2, ..., k+1\}$ across its permutations. Let us denote this number by $\bar{I}_{k+1}$.

\begin{align*}
\bar{I}_{k+1} &= \frac{1}{(k+1)!} \left[ \frac{k(k-1)}{4} k! + \left(\frac{k(k-1)}{4} + 1\right) k! + ... + \left( \frac{k(k-1)}{4} + k \right) k! \right] \\
& = \frac{1}{k+1} \left[ \frac{k(k-1)}{4} + \left(\frac{k(k-1)}{4} + 1\right) + ... + \left( \frac{k(k-1)}{4} + k \right) \right] \\
& = \frac{1}{k+1} \left[ \frac{k(k-1)(k+1)}{4} + \frac{k(k+1)}{2} \right] \\
& = \frac{k(k-1)}{4} + \frac{k}{2}  \\
& = \frac{(k+1)k}{4} \\
\end{align*}

With this we have shown that $P(k+1)$ holds and the proof by induction is complete. We conclude that the average number of inversions of $\{1, 2, ..., n\}$ across its permutations, which is equal to the average Kendall tau distance between its permutations, is $ \frac{n(n-1)}{4}$.

Q.E.D.